# How to use asp.net and visual basic to make a page stay translated after clicking the desired language?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

so today, I have tried a turorial from https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-Multilingual-website-Support-and-display-Multiple-Languages-English-French-in-ASPNet.aspx

However, when I clicked on a different page, I discovered that it was not auto translated and i need to click the language everytime, despite the fact that I had added the drop down in Master's site. Could someone kindly help me? This is my coding:

Master's site Front-end:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 text-right " style="padding-top:2%">
      <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Italic="True" Font-Size="Smaller" Text="Bahasa"></asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLanguages" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged = "OnSelectedIndexChanged" style="margin-right:2em" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="Black" Height="38px" Width="109px">
        <asp:ListItem Text="English" Value="en-us" />
          <asp:ListItem Text="Malay" Value="Ms" />
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <hr />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
 </div>
```

Master's Back-end

```
 Protected Sub OnSelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        If Not Me.IsPostBack Then
            If ddlLanguages.Items.FindByValue(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name) IsNot Nothing Then
                ddlLanguages.Items.FindByValue(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name).Selected = True
            End If
        End If
  End Sub
```

Basic Page's class *(where I inherited in all aspx page)*

```
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Globalization

Public Class BasePage
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Protected Overrides Sub InitializeCulture()
        Dim language As String = "en-us"

        'Detect User's Language.
        If Request.UserLanguages IsNot Nothing Then
            'Set the Language.
            language = Request.UserLanguages(0)
        End If

        'Check if PostBack is caused by Language DropDownList.
        If Request.Form("__EVENTTARGET") IsNot Nothing AndAlso Request.Form("__EVENTTARGET").Contains("ddlLanguages") Then
            'Set the Language.
            language = Request.Form(Request.Form("__EVENTTARGET"))
        End If

        'Set the Culture.
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo(language)
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo(language)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: A common method is to use a [cookie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) to store the data on the client. That way, the next time they visit the site, the language can stay on their chosen one. (Or, if the user has to log in, you could store their preferences in a database.)

Comment: And keep in mind that sample you linked to does NOT do ANY translation for you. It is a assumed that you have a resource file, and for each different language, you will pull values into the markup based on the given resource file. In other words, that example allows you to have different languages, but it is assumed that you create the text for each language - it does not auto-matic translate  your text, it is assumed that you do this, or you hire someone to do this for you. So, that sample shows how to use a resource file, and in that file is the text to display. No translate involved here.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal even if i put session or cookie it won't translate?

Comment: Link to the article says ZERO about translation. The title of the article is "Support and display" multiple languages. It does not say, hint, suggest, imply, propose, or talk about translation at all. Look close at the article, you are to use "expressions" in the web page, and which expression to display is based on the language setting, and then the text you saved in the resource file is to be displayed. In other words, that text has to be already translated by you, and saved as translated text. Again, ZERO is talked about, or stated, or suggested in that example about "translate"

Comment: I know and understand the article, but even if I use session or cookie, the value of the dropdown list will be retained, am I correct? and whenever the value is selected, the page will 'change' to the language I set in the resources file, which will never work? Do you have any suggestions for putting a translation in an asp.net website other than using the Google Translate API?